# Is there a must use framework to design dapps that works well with Truffle?

Tags: dapps, javascript, dapp-design

I am trying to develop a dapp that works on a web browser that will also contain a website made in a popular UI framework (let's say angular) rather than building a html/css manually.

Right now I'm using Truffle with a server-local test blockchain with some basic functions and html, so I'm thinking about nodejs-based frameworks maybe a better choice than angular since both frameworks use nodeJS and would have to run the same js version since it's the same web-server/folder OR sharing the same nodeJS would make things complicated like for example having shared modules but each fw need different versions of the module.

Is there any, more popular than others or rather must-use, framework when it comes to developing blockchain webapps?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, after working with Truffle I realize no, the framework will not interact with the inner, designer framework inside "src" unless is programmed to, so if  both fw use nodeJS you will have 2 separate modules folders that don't interact to each other, so no worries about dependency conflicts.

In fact you can have a framework in a completely different language like, django, angular, rails, etc and it will talk to the blockchain the same way using web3.

Comment: I am reposting this question because it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your decentralized application does not need to interact with Truffle or any Solidity development suite at all.

DApp development is a two-stage process:

1. Smart contract development (This is where you use Truffle, HardHat, or whatever.)
2. Web application development (This only requires the ABI(s) of the smart contract(s) you have developed in the first step, nothing more.)

Answer (score 0):

Truffle developers have written [Drizzle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/drizzle). I'm not a frontend developer so I can't say if it is good or not.